# How to link javascript function to html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*New question following suggestions:

HTML head contains:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" rel="img1">Link1</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a a href="javascript:;" rel="img2">Link2</a>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artdesigner/emoticons-2/256/cant-believe-it-icon.png" id="img1" class="images"/>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artdesigner/emoticons-2/256/too-much-icon.png" id="img2" class="images"/>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: large;
}

#table1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#table1 th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#table1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#box {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1200px;
}

.images {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And my Javascript:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('img').hide();    
    $('#'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This should mean that when the  Link1 is clicked, the first image appears and when the  Link 2 is clicked, the second image appears and the first goes away (the images are on top of each other in CSS). However, when either of the two are clicked, nothing happens. Any suggestions why this may be the case?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Comment: Update: After deleting the .images {display:none;} in the CSS, both images are showing, but the links still don't do anything - shouldn't the jQuery cause one image to hide when a <td> is clicked though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

Save your javascript code into a file with **.js** extension `code.js` then import it to your html file using `<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>`

Or you can put your code directly in your **HTML** file in the **Head** part like this :

```
  <head>
    <script>
    // Your Javascript Code
    </script>
  </head>
```

And don't forget to import jQuery

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I put copy the jQuery part directly into the <head>, then link to the javascript file in the head, changing the source? After doing that, and removing the href attributes, when I click on it, nothing happens. I have included the document ready function part as other comments have said too.

Comment: u can't use the two methods at the same time. either you make a .js file and import it. or you write the code directly in the header tag and between <script></script>. and the important thing is after choosing a method.you must to include the jQuerry.js (the two last lines) in your html file

Comment: Okay I'm seriously confused after never working with javascript or jQuery before, so let me try to explain exactly what I've done. I saved the second part of my code in my question as a .js file. Then I linked to that in the head (not writing the code between <script> tags. I'm then unsure about the whole jQuery part - is my code javascript or jQuery? and what do I need to do to amend that? I have removed the href attributes that were in my original question. I have added onclick="ChangeImage();" to the <a> tag. I have copied the coding with the document ready part to fix my javascript file.

Comment: And finally, I've added document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = ChangeImage(); to the top of the .js file, and the first line from my original code (don't know if its javascript or jQuery) now reads $('a').click(function ChangeImage(){
so that the Change Image is the function to call.

Comment: The code works right. My Friend you need to import **jquery-ui.js**

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aladdin_messadi/f5SVL/2/)

Comment: So just copy the two lines of code above into the <head>?

Comment: put this also in the header of the html file <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Keeping the same sources?

Comment: include your **a.js** and the **jquery-ui.js** in the header.
**jQuery-ui.js** is needed because you're using jQuery in **a.js**

Comment: Ah I think I've spotted the issue now, my .js file contains just what I have said, however, that is in fact jQuery. Again I apologize as I have never worked with either. So my javascript links are not needed, just jQuery links, and how do I save it as a jQuery file, not .js or is it the same and is just the links that matter?

Comment: You're welcome my friend :) great that you have solved the problem.

Comment: hmm... very almost there (I hope) but when I run it in jsfiddle or when previewed from my entire webpage, it doesn't work. Here's it copied into jsfiddle - the picture will be overlayed in my webpage, other than that, when the 2 links are clicked, the pictures don't do anything - in case I haven't been clear, what I want it to do is when Link 1 is clicked, only the first image is on screen, and when the second is clicked, only the second is visible.

Comment: in right after the **Frameworks & Extensions** select **jQuery1.10.1** to Import jQuery Library

Comment: Surely the href links you included in the jsfiddle link to nowhere? When I click on the links nothing changes, and opening them in a new tab opens up a blank page.

Comment: Think I've got that part sorted - the original included the following CSS: img{display:none}
a{color:gray;text-decoration:none;}
a.active{color:black} when this is put into your jsfiddle it works.

Comment: Everything works on the jsfiddle so I know I'm very almost there :). But after copying the code over, the images don't show. In the head, I have: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
as I found in another person's question which they said worked, and the source is right. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you don't need to import jQuerry Library in JSFiddle. the site do that background. so they ask to use the select option to select the library you want to include

Comment: No, I mean when I put this code from jsfiddle into microsoft expressions web, I added the code I mentioned in the head, as instructed by another person's question, but when I preview my webpage, the images don't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

Of course at first you have to include your javascript file in the html, best practice include it in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/destination/to/file.js"> </script>
```

then in the

```
<a href="#" onclick="FunctionToCall();">Link</a>
```

and make sure your javascript file is modified to get the element by its id to run the function properly.

Comment: What would be the function to call from my javascript file (sorry haven't got round to learning javascript so I only know the extreme basics).

Comment: Lets assume that your function is called, ChangeImage which is declared in javascript as:
function ChangeImage() {
//..... Rest of your code;
}
At the very beginning in your js file type:
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = ChangeImage();

Comment: I would advise against declaring event handlers in HTML code. Use $(document).ready(function() { $("a").click(FunctionToCall()) }) instead.

Comment: Every time I see any kind of inline javascript, I kill a kitten. Stop hurting the kittens!

Comment: Should I get rid of the href attributes this way as mentioned in the other comment?

Comment: If your link doesnt go any where, then yes.